# Problemas com RibbonComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Boa tarde, estamos desenvolvendo uma ferramenta de edição de texto. Nela estamos usando os menus com a "RibbonControlsLibrary", e até o momento tudo certo.
Quando resolvi utilizar o RibbonComboBox é que começou o problema, me baseando em um exemplo tentei chegar a uma solução, mas não consigo passar as informações criadas para a UI.

XAML:

```
<r:RibbonComboBox x:Name="rcbFontFamily" DataContext="{x:Static data:EditorTexto_ViewModel.FontFace}">
    <r:RibbonGallery MaxColumnCount="1">
        <r:RibbonGallery.GalleryItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontFamily="{Binding}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </r:RibbonGallery.GalleryItemTemplate>
    </r:RibbonGallery>
```

FontFace:

```
public static ControlData FontFace
    {
        get
        {
            lock (_lockObject)
            {
                string Str = "Font Face";

                if (!_dataCollection.ContainsKey(Str))
                {
                    GalleryData<FontFamily> galleryData = new GalleryData<FontFamily>()
                    {
                        SelectedItem = SystemFonts.MessageFontFamily,
                    };

                    GalleryCategoryData<FontFamily> allFontsCategoryData = new GalleryCategoryData<FontFamily>()
                    {
                        Text = "Todas as fontes"
                    };

                    foreach (FontFamily fontFamily in System.Windows.Media.Fonts.SystemFontFamilies)
                    {
                        allFontsCategoryData.GalleryItemDataCollection.Add(fontFamily);

                    }

                    galleryData.CategoryDataCollection.Add(allFontsCategoryData);

                    Action<FontFamily> ChangeFontFace = delegate(FontFamily parameter)
                    {
                        if (AppWindow != null)
                        {
                            AppWindow.ChangeFontFace(parameter);
                        }
                    };

                    Func<FontFamily, bool> CanChangeFontFace = delegate(FontFamily parameter)
                    {
                        if (AppWindow != null)
                        {
                            return AppWindow.CanChangeFontFace(parameter);
                        }

                        return false;
                    };

                    Action<FontFamily> PreviewFontFace = delegate(FontFamily parameter)
                    {
                        if (AppWindow != null)
                        {
                            AppWindow.PreviewFontFace(parameter);
                        }
                    };

                    Action CancelPreviewFontFace = delegate()
                    {
                        if (AppWindow != null)
                        {
                            AppWindow.CancelPreviewFontFace();
                        }
                    };

                    galleryData.Command = new officersoft.editor.MainWindow.PreviewDelegateCommand<FontFamily>(ChangeFontFace, CanChangeFontFace, PreviewFontFace, CancelPreviewFontFace);

                    _dataCollection[Str] = galleryData;
                }

                return _dataCollection[Str];
            }
        }
    }
```

Se precisarem de mais informações é só pedir e desculpem por qualquer erro, sou novo no c#/wpf.

**Solução**:
Para setar a informação foi necessário somente criar o seguinte código XAML:

```
<r:RibbonComboBox 
    x:Name="rcbFontFamily" 
    SelectionBoxWidth="160"
    IsEditable="True">
    <r:RibbonGallery
        Name="_rgFontFamily"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        Command="{StaticResource FontFamilyHandler}">
        <r:RibbonGalleryCategory
            Name="_rgcFontFamily"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}}"/>
    </r:RibbonGallery>
</r:RibbonComboBox>
```

Se houver alguma dúvida, só perguntar.

Comment: e também é novato por aqui. Seja Bem vindo ao site StackOverFlow. Você fez bem em postar seu código podendo assim ser ajudado, mas você disse que houve erro, e esse erro nós não estamos vendo. Poderia mostrar com mais clareza esse erro?

Comment: Digo erro, no sentido de falta de conhecimento em programação com c# usando wpf...
O que não está acontecendo é a informação processada pelo método FontFace, estar contida no RibbonComboBox.

Comment: Qual erro ocorre? Nenhum?  você utiliza Visual Studio?

Comment: Nenhum, simplesmente não é inserido a informação no RibbonComboBox, acho que falta algo no XAML ou no código. Tenho várias dúvidas se essa é a forma a se fazer mesmo.

Comment: Onde vc pegou esse código pronto?

Comment: Peguei em algum discussão no stackoverflow.com, o meu problema inicial era que eu tinha as informações preenchidas no RibbonComboBox, mas quando eu selecionava não alterava o SelectedItem.
Após algumas pesquisas, encontrei essa "solução" e tentei adaptar ela para o meu projeto.
E sim, estou usando Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução: Para setar a informação foi necessário somente criar o seguinte código XAML:

```
<r:RibbonComboBox 
    x:Name="rcbFontFamily" 
    SelectionBoxWidth="160"
    IsEditable="True">
    <r:RibbonGallery
        Name="_rgFontFamily"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
        Command="{StaticResource FontFamilyHandler}">
        <r:RibbonGalleryCategory
            Name="_rgcFontFamily"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}}"/>
    </r:RibbonGallery>
</r:RibbonComboBox>
```

Se houver alguma dúvida, só perguntar.